# Filtering inputs

Tags: php, forms

Alright, so I have written this function to filter inputs received from a form. 
For example the correct input would be `foobar`, but people can misspell it as `fo'bar'. The ' should not be there.
I have written this simple function which does what is required. (Need to remove the ' from the inputs).
But what would be a more better way to perform this ?

My function :

```
function normalize_string($string)
{
    $newString = "";
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($string);$i++)
    {
        if($string[$i] != "'")
        {
            $newString = $newString . $string[$i];
        }
    }
    return $newString;
}
```

Array

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $db->insert('customers', array(
  'Businessname'  =>  $_POST['BusinessnameTextbox'],
  'Salutation' =>  $_POST['SalutationTextbox'],
  'Firstname'  => $_POST['FirstnameTextbox'],
  'Middle'  => $_POST['MiddleTextbox'],
  'Lastname'  => $_POST['LastnameTextbox'],
  'Zipcode'  => $_POST['ZipcodeTextbox'],
  'Housenumber' => $_POST['HousenumberTextbox'],
  'Street'  => $_POST['StreetTextbox'],
  'Place'   => $_POST['PlaceTextbox'],
  'Country'  => $_POST['CountryTextbox'],
  'Phone1'  => $_POST['Phone1Textbox'],
  'Phone2'  => $_POST['Phone2Textbox'],
  'Phone3'  => $_POST['Phone3Textbox'],
  'Phone4'  => $_POST['Phone4Textbox'] 
 ));
}
```

Comment: All the downvotes should come with a reason.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use regular expressions, as in

```
$lastname = preg_replace("/'/", "", $_POST['LastnameTextbox']);
```

Just curious, how would d'Artagnan register at your site?